# why SELECT fails with but table exists?

Tags: mysql, pdo

If I create a new table im not able to select something from it with PDO.
MySQL Workbench let me SELECT something and old tables are working well anyway, but as I said, I can't SELECT something from new tables, with exactly the same setup (eg. InnoDB,UTF-8) than the old working ones.

Here one example errormessage from my log:

```
[Thu Oct 18 12:34:56 2012] [error] [client 12.345.678.90] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.tablename' doesn't exist' in /var/www/project/file.php:928
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/project/file.php(928): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/project/file.php(946): Interact->addSomething(Array)
#2 /var/www/project/index.php(22): Interact->handleAction(Array)
#3 {main}
thrown in /var/www/project/file.php on line 928, referer:
(12:34:56) user: http://user.domain.com/?longthingy=wakenmgwjakngpwjani
```

Has anyone made similar experiences or ideas how to solve this mess?

Comment: Are your database/table really called `database.tablename`?

Comment: Does your PHP code log in as a different user than the one you log into MySQL workbench with?  Also, table names can be case sensitive depending on the platform (Windows, Linux, etc) and other settings.  Check to make sure your case matches.

Comment: yes, the table really exists. I just switch the tablename in my query to an older one and the query works.

in mysql-administrator, every query works, but within php with pdo it fails for uncertain reason.

i am really sure, the tablenames are correct and as i mentioned, i found out that brand new created tables don't work too :( just old ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were too dumb to recognize that I connected with mysql-administrator to our old server.